# How can I better manage my console windows?

Tags: linux, bash, gnome, console

I'm using Gnome/Debian and I'm constantly always opening new console windows ( I have my Windows key mapped to invoke gnome-terminal ).

It's a bit frustrating because after a few hours of work I'll have say, 20 windows open and I don't know which is which.

**Aside from the obvious ( closing them more often )**, I'm looking for any advice for better window management. I've tried xmonad in the past but it's a vim-like curve and kinda hard to get used to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a single terminal window. Run [GNU screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/)

Comment: +1 An additional benefit is that `screen` also works in SSH sessions, so you can use the same commands for local and remote work. And if you want to, you can still have multiple console windows, each with a `screen` session...

Comment: You can even have the same screen session open in several terminal windows if you like. Put "multiuser on" into your .screenc and use "screen -xr" to attach.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to remove the key mapping and instead to learn the shortcut to open a new tab inside the terminal window, in this way you'll have all your sessions grouped together having the possibility to quit the ones you don't use.

Comment: you could also name the tabs & sessions